# Cannot access Dictionary defined outside a function

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, scope

Im have dictionary which I want to fill within a function like this:

```
  var categories = [String:String]()

  func addCategory (cat: String, symptomID: String) -> () {
    categories[cat] = symptomID
  }
```

But I keep getting `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`.

Considering the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) I'm not able to see why this does not work.

Interestingly defining the dictionary within the function does not get me this error.

Comment: When do you call this function? Your code does not have any erreur.

Comment: i think i found the problem. I'm using this within a struct which apperently isn't working

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I don't understand why exactly you are creating a function to add key/values to a dictionary. Just use `updateValue(value: Value, forKey key: Key)`-method of dictionary:

```
categories.updateValue("value", forKey:"key")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippest which I have tried and worked for me.

Please check and update on it.

```
var categories = [String:String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(self.categories.description);
    self.addCategory("Viral" as String, symptomID:"Savaj" as String);
    println(self.categories.description);

}
func addCategory (cat: String, symptomID: String) -> () {
    categories[cat] = symptomID
}
```

The output is like :

```
[:]
[Viral: Savaj]
```

HTH,
Enjoy Coding !!